# I get raw HTML instead of data from API in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started to build a hangman game. I found a great Wordnik API that should allow me to get random words. Here's my code on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/summerfreeze/pen/NAkdKR). I do not understand why I keep getting raw HTML instead of a word. I tried to fix it with `Content-Type: application/json`but this didn't work.

**HTML**

```
<body layout="column" ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="controller">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
{{words}}
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
myApp.controller('controller', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.title = "Hangman";
      $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://crossorigin.me/http://api.wordnik.com/words.json/randomWord?minLength=5&api_key=c3847c4934574ce6cf81c45640103f2e5fab2284ab2e7badc"
      })
      .then(function(response) {
            $scope.words = response.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {})
}]);
```

Comment: Check your URL. I see http:// with another http://

Comment: yes, that's a CORS proxy

Comment: @summfreeze Notice in your codepen in your url the placement of v4. It is before words.json. http://developer.wordnik.com/docs.html#!/words/getRandomWords_get_3

Comment: I solved it, thank you.

Comment: Here is a working http://codepen.io/bhantol/pen/ambJgo

Answer (score 0):

You used bad url, literally 2 urls :)

Try this url:

```
"http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/words.json/randomWord?api_key=c3847c4934574ce6cf81c45640103f2e5fab2284ab2e7badc"
```

then you get json response.

Comment: without it I get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load api.wordnik.com/words.json/…. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 's.codepen.io'; is therefore not allowed access."

Answer (score 0):

[Modified your codepen](http://codepen.io/bhantol/pen/ambJgo) Fix the url like I said in the comment. (Unfortunately this does not work at my work due to proxy avoidance issues so had to test on my phone.)

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "https://crossorigin.me/http://api.wordnik.com/v4/words.json/randomWords?hasDictionaryDef=false&minCorpusCount=0&maxCorpusCount=-1&minDictionaryCount=1&maxDictionaryCount=-1&minLength=5&maxLength=-1&limit=10&api_key=a2a73e7b926c924fad7001ca3111acd55af2ffabf50eb4ae5"})                .then(function(response) {
        $scope.words = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response)
          {
           $scope.words = response;
            console.log(response);
   });
```